# Android Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was experimenting on Android fragments, hence I created two fragments `ListFragment` and `DetailFragment`. The problem is that when I click on the `ListFragment` and call a `DetailFragment` method to show the selected item from the `ListFragment` no result is shown on the `DetailFragment`. Here is the `DetailFragment` Code :

```
    private static final String DETAIL_FRAG_TAG = "detail_fragment";
private Context appContext = null;
private TextView lblItemDetail = null;
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflate the fragment layout
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments_detail_fragment, container, false);
    lblItemDetail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_itemDetail);


 //at this point the TextView is not null===>see L0g.i
Log.i(DETAIL_FRAG_TAG, " ---MyDetailFragment---oncreateView()--lblItemDetail =[" +    lblItemDetail + "]");

    // get the fragment activity context
    appContext = this.getActivity();
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}

/**
 * show the details of the item selected on the listFragment.
 * @param itemDetail - the details of the item selected on ListFragment.
 */
public void showLstItemDetail(String itemDetail) {

    if (lblItemDetail != null) {
        // the View to show Text should not be Null.
        lblItemDetail.setText(itemDetail);
    }

    //at this point calling this method shows 
           that    the `TextView` is Null yet it's 
       initialized in the 
        oncreate() as a class member variable ---why am i 
   getting Null after the `oncreate` is finished.
    Log.i(DETAIL_FRAG_TAG,    "------showItemDetail---------msg=[" + itemDetail + "] txt=[" + lblItemDetail + "]");
}



//when I create an instance of `MYDetailFragment`  and call the method to show the details of item Selected on the `DetailFragment` the `TextView` will be null. Why?

   MYDetailFragment detailFrag = new MyDetailFragment();
   detailFrag.showLstItemDetail("Selected List Item");
```

Comment: Can you tell us how and when do you call `MYDetailFragment detailFrag` ? Can you c/p all your Fragment code ?

Comment: You should pass the detail to the fragment using the setArguments and getArguments. Currenlty you are calling    detailFrag.showLstItemDetail("Selected List Item"); -> this function should be called in fragment itself. Why? because at that time the fragment ui isnt loaded yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

during those two lines:

```
MYDetailFragment detailFrag = new MyDetailFragment();
detailFrag.showLstItemDetail("Selected List Item");
```

the `onCreateView()` was not called yet. That means the fragment rootView was never created and the TextView was never created YET!

the view will only be created after you use a fragment transaction, to put that fragment in the layout, the fragment will then be attached to the activity (onAttach()) and after a few more callbacks onCreateView() will be called. Only then anything can be set to it.

The standard good practice to pass parameters to a fragment is using a Bundle. Look an example code:

on the activity:

```
MYDetailFragment detailFrag = new MYDetailFragment();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
detailFrag.setArguments(b);
b.putString("detail", value);
// then proceed to the fragment transaction
```

then on your fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// inflate the fragment layout
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments_detail_fragment, container, false);
lblItemDetail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_itemDetail);
Bundle b = getArguments();
lblItemDetail.setText(b.getString("details"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please verify the following tutorial about fragments if any useful information **[Click here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html)**